# Why pseudoscalar can decay to photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, parity

I think I have a misunderstanding of quantum numbers. We know that photon  $\gamma$ has negative parity and pseudoscalar $P$ by definition has negative parity.

So one would think that decay $P \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$ is not allowed, because initial state has parity $-1$ and final state has parity $(-1)(-1)=1$.

1. However, one can write effective Lagrangian containing $PF_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$ and study $P\rightarrow \gamma \gamma$ which has non-zero amplitude.
2. In Two Higgs Doublet Model, a pseudoscalar can decay into photons via triangular loop diagram.

So it seems that quantum numbers do not allow this decay, however it still happens. 
If someone understands what I have in mind, I would very much appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting about the parity of the spatial wavefunctions, which provides extra sign flips. For example, if the two photons come out in an $s$-wave, the spatial wavefunction has positive parity, while if they come out in a $p$-wave, it has negative parity. This is just like how the parity of $|\ell m \rangle$ in the hydrogen atom is $(-1)^\ell$.

In this case, you've shown that parity forbids the $s$-wave decay, but the $p$-wave is allowed.

Comment: Initial state pseudoscalar has total angular momentum $J=0$ and photons have spin 1, if the final state also has J=0 it is impossible to have p-wave ($l=1$) state, because 2-1 = 1. Angular momentum can only be conserved if final state photons have $l =2$, but then your argument of $(-1)^l$ does not work

Comment: @Wagm No, that's not quite right. Just because the photons have spin $1$ doesn't mean that two photons will have spin $2$. Instead by the usual Clebsch-Gordan decomposition two photons have spin $0$, $1$, or $2$. Either the spin $0$ or spin $1$ components can then add with the $J = 1$ of the $p$-wave to yield a total spin $0$, again by Clebsch-Gordan.

Comment: Whoops, replace “either the spin 0 or spin 1” with “the spin 1”.